# Teste Ks e qui quadrado para dados de confiabilidade no R

Tags: r, testes

Estou utilizando modelos paramétricos para o cálculo de alguns itens de confiabilidade.

A dúvida é como realizar os testes de aderência (Teste *Kolmogorov-Smirnov*- KS e o *Qui quadrado* - χ2) .

Tentei utilizando a função “ks.test”

> (ex: ks.test(arquivo$tempo,"pweibull", shape= gama,scale= alfa_wei))

e

> “chisq.test” (ex: chisq.test(rlnorm(n,mean = Y, sd = sy)).

Entretanto o `p-valor` não está correto, porém no teste `ks` a estatística está correta (D). Como realizo esses testes no R para dados de confiabilidade?

Dados utilizados foram:

```
Tempo tipo
 794    1
 676    1
 573    1
 484    1
 406    1
 339    1
 282    1
 233    1
 191    1
 156    1
 126    1
 102    1
 81     1
 64     1
```

Resultados R:

> gama = 1.476715
>   alfa_wei= 357.5189

*One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test*

> data:  arquivo$Tempo
>   D = 0.10253, p-value = 0.995
>   alternative hypothesis: two-sided

O resultado correto do p-valor deveria ser:
D = 0,1006, p-value = 0,386

Para o teste qui quadrado não obtive sucesso.

Como faço esses testes no R para dados de confiabilidade?